# javascript promise chains not waiting for previous promise to execute

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm struggling to understand javascript promises. I have a simple list and I want to highlight each element in turn by adding an "active" class, with a pause between each.

So I have the following mark up -

```
<h2 class="step step1">Promise</h2>
<h2 class="step step2">Promise</h2>
<h2 class="step step3">Promise</h2>
<h2 class="step step4">Promise</h2>
```

and 2 javascript promises. First to set the step -

```
function setStep(step) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("Step ", step, new Date())
        document.querySelectorAll('.step').forEach(function (match) {
            match.classList.remove("active");
        });

        document.querySelector(".step" + step).classList.add("active");
        resolve(step);
    })
}
```

and a second that implements a wait -

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

and then I'm trying to chain it all together like this -

```
wait(1000)
    .then(function () { setStep(1) })
    .then(wait(1000))
    .then(function () { setStep(2) })
    .then(wait(1000))
    .then(function () { setStep(3) })
```

The first wait seem to execute as expected but then everything else appears to happen together and step 3 is highlighted, with no waits in between. The console messages all show the same timestamp.

What am I overlooking?

The complete code  is as follows -

```
<style>
    .active {
        background-color: #C00;
        color: #FFF;
    }
</style>

<h2 class="step step1">Step 1</h2>
<h2 class="step step2">Step 2</h2>
<h2 class="step step3">Step 3</h2>

<script>
  const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  function setStep(step) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("Step ", step, new Date())
        document.querySelectorAll('.step').forEach(function (match) {
            match.classList.remove("active");
        });

        document.querySelector(".step" + step).classList.add("active");
        resolve(step);
    })
}

  wait(1000)
    .then(function () { setStep(1) })
    .then(wait(1000))
    .then(function () { setStep(2) })
    .then(wait(1000))
    .then(function () { setStep(3) })
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference to `.then()`, not a promise.  So change this:

```
.then(wait(1000))
```

to this:

```
.then(wait.bind(null, 1000))
```

or this:

```
.then(() => wait(1000))
```

`.then()` only works properly when you pass it a function reference that it can call later.  When you do `.then(wait(1000))`, you're executing `wait(1000)` immediately and passing the return value (a promise) to `.then()`.  That is not how `.then()` works and you didn't want to be executing `wait(1000)` immediately either.

---

Or, you could make a new  `waitFn()` that returns a function that could be used in the way you were doing (because it returns a function when called):

```
function waitFn(t) {
    return function() { return wait(t);}
}
```

Then, you could do this:

```
wait(1000)
  .then(function () { setStep(1) })
  .then(waitFn(1000))
  .then(function () { setStep(2) })
  .then(waitFn(1000))
.  then(function () { setStep(3) })
```

Comment: That did the trick. Is it possible to rewrite the wait function as a single function that will allow me to use it as I was originally?

Comment: @benophobia - No, that's not possible. To start a promise chain as in `fn(1000).then(...)`, it has to return a promise. To be used as `p.then(fn(1000))`, it has to return a function. One function cannot be both unless it returned different types in different circumstances which is probably not good design. That's why I offered two separate functions to cover both cases.